# Add a module to jboss

Tags: java, jboss

I want to add the sevenzipjbinding library to an old project.

But after adding the module I get a **NoClassDefFoundError net/sf/sevenzipjbinding/IInStream**

I've looked at various topics and documentation, but haven't found a solution yet. Any ideas?

**Module path: *modules/net/sf/sevenzipjbinding/main***

**This is my module structure:**

```
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="net.sf.sevenzipjbinding">
  <resources>
    <resource-root path="sevenzipjbinding-16.02-2.01.jar"/>
    <resource-root path="sevenzipjbinding-all-platforms-16.02-2.01.jar"/>
    <!-- Insert resources here -->
  </resources>
</module>
```

**This a jboss-deployment-structure:**

```
<jboss-deployment-structure>
   <deployment>
      <dependencies>
         <module name="net.sf.sevenzipjbinding"/>
      </dependencies>
   </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

**And pom.xml**

```
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>net.sf.sevenzipjbinding</groupId>
    <artifactId>sevenzipjbinding-all-platforms</artifactId>
    <version>16.02-2.01</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>net.sf.sevenzipjbinding</groupId>
    <artifactId>sevenzipjbinding</artifactId>
    <version>16.02-2.01</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: Where is the `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` located and what kind of deployment is it?

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins I solved the problem by adding the module to the global modules section of the standalone.xml structure. I don't know if this is right, but it works for me

Comment: I won't say it's wrong, it just adds the module dependency to all deployments. However, if that worked that would mean you're either using an EAR and need to add the module dependency to sub-modules or your `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` is located in the wrong place.